# Problem using godoc to start a local doc server

Tags: go

godoc won't return packages list

Build version go1.11.5.

go env:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=E:\Go work
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build908876718=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Currently learning go, checking go packages docs a lot, so I am trying to start a local go docments server using godoc. the command I am using is:

```
godoc -http=:54321
```

The server started without problem, but when I click the "Packages" button on top of the page or visit localhost:54321 it gave me this:

```
\src\temp.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
```

instead of packages list like the online doc.
But if I visit http://localhost:54321/pkg/io/ or any other packages directly it works fine.

I have an empty temp.go file under my e:\go work\src, so I am pretty sure that's where the error coming from.

What I want is godoc return package list when I visit http://localhost:54321/pkg/, just like visit the online doc https://golang.org/pkg/

Comment: Yes, the empty temp.go file is indeed the problem. Put at least the package line into it.

Comment: @Henry Thank you, I put package main into the empty temp.go file, and it worked. Is there a way to let godoc ignore GOPATH? I just want go builtin packages doc

Comment: You could set GOPATH to some empty directory for the godoc invocation.

Comment: @Henry How to do that? godoc only have -goroot argument, no -gopath

Comment: if you are on linux you could do `GOPATH=something godoc`.

Answer (score 0):

Put at least the package line into temp.go file or remove that file fix the problem. It seems any file directly under $GOPATH/src/ contain syntax error will cause problem